# Conditional Optional Argument Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Currently I have this example which demonstrates conditional arguments, The value of the second argument passed in will depend on what the type of the first is.

```
type Check<G, T> = T extends number ? string : number

function Example<T>(arg: T) { 
    return function <P>(arg: Check<P, T>) { 

    }
}

// Valid:

Example('hello')(1)
Example(1)('hello')
```

How can I change the code above to make this example work?

```
Example()(1)
Example(1)()
```

The issue when I add `?` it make's it permanently optional, and without it its required.

Comment: Isn't `G` unused?

Answer (score 2):

`void` does the trick!

```
type Check<G, T> = T extends number ? void : number

function Example<T>(arg?: T) { 
    return function <P>(arg: Check<P, T>) { 

    }
}

Example()(1)
Example(1)()
```